# Get the hour minute second data from time string in android?

Tags: android

In my application i got arrival  time and departure time from JSON in the form  String 2014-12-15T23:00:00 and 2014-12-15T13:30:00 respectively. Now i need know the hours in the string and difference between the departure time  and arrival time.

Comment: Search on `Google` for that there are many answers available.

Comment: Show code. What did you try?

Comment: Always put your code which  have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    String dtDeparture = "2014-12-15T13:30:00";
    String dtArrival = "2014-12-15T23:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dateDeparture = format.parse(dtDeparture);
        Date dateArrival = format.parse(dtArrival);
        dateArrival.compareTo(dateDeparture);
        long diff = dateArrival.getTime() - dateDeparture.getTime();
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff) - hours*60;
        System.out.println(hours + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou Mongi Zaidi. helped me alot.